# why this graphql is showing TypeError: (...) is undefined

Tags: graphql, gatsby

Hi I am trying to show featured post on blog with graphql, why it's not working?
I want to show first post with different style - like featured and rest like a post list so I try to create 2 diffrent graphql but I am stuck with it.

```
export default function Featured() {
  return (
    <StaticQuery
      query={graphql`
              query HeadingQuery {
                allMarkdownRemark {
                  edges {
                    node {
                      frontmatter {
                        title
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
              
        
      `}
      render={data=> (
        <h1>{data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.node.frontmatter.title}</h1>
      )}
    />
  )
}
```

there is TypeError: (...) is undefined

Comment: `edges[0]` ? what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your query working in the GraphQL playground ([localhost:8000/___graphql](http://localhost:8000/___graphql))?

In addition, your render method has an error. `edges`, is an array, so you should loop through them to show your content or enter position by position specifically:

```
<h1>{data.allMarkdownRemark.edges[0].node.frontmatter.title}</h1>
```

Comment: great thank you I didn't know I can specifi position of it. Can you show me how to loop throug it? Or how to show posts from  1 to 5 positions?

Comment: `{data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(({node})=><h1>{node.frontmatter.title}</h1>)}`